# I have to build a query in which I have to get data between two dates

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have two type of client fixed and hourly and clients can be fixed and hourly both for example in January the Client A was on fixed price of $200/month and in Feb he was on hourly then from March he was on fixed price of $250/month since then.

There are three tables.

1. `fixed_client_info` which stores the client type (history of type fixed). It has `client_id,budget,start_date,end_date` these columns
2. `client_info` which has the client info with its current type
3. `client_budget` which has the budget info of the client like which emp work how many hours and client rate.It has `client_id,date,hour,rate,emp_id columns`

Now I have to query to get budget from jan-march and they way it should is when the client was on fixed date then it should bring the budget from `fixed_client_info` else if should bring the budget from `client_budget`. This should be in one query.

Can any one please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: From where i should get know is client has fixed date ?